# Windows could not start the Apache2 on Local Computer - problem

Tags: windows, windows-xp, apache2

During the installation of Apache2 I got the following message into cmd window:

> Installing the Apache2.2 service The
>   Apache2.2 service is successfully
>   installed. Testing httpd.conf....
>
> Errors reported here must be corrected
>   before the service can be started.
>   httpd.exe: Could not reliably
>   determine the server's fully qualified
>   domain name , using 192.168.1.3 for
>   ServerName (OS 10048)Only one usage of
>   each socket address (protocol/network
>   address/port) is normally permitted. 
>   : make_sock: could not bind to address
>   0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to
>   open logs Note the errors or messages
>   above, and press the  key to
>   exit.  24...

and after installing everything look fine, but it isn't. If I try to start service I got the following message:

> Windows could not start the Apache2 on
>   Local Computer.  For more information,
>   review the System Event Log.  If this
>   is a non-Micorsoft service, contact
>   the service vendor, and refer to
>   service-specific error code 1.

Apach2 version is 2.2.9

Does anyone have the same problem, or could help me.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

There is some other program listening on port 80, usual suspects are

1. Skype (Listens on port 80)
2. NOD32 (Add Apache to the IMON exceptions' list for it to allow apache to bind)
3. Some other antivirus (Same as above)

Way to correct it is either shutting down the program that's using the port 80 or configure it to use a different port or configure Apache to listen on a different port with the Listen directive in httpd.conf. In the case of antivirus configure the antivirus to allow Apache to bind on the port you have chosen.

Way to diagnose which app, if any, has bound to port 80 is run the netstat with those options, look for :80 next to the local IP address (second column) and find the PID (last column). Then, on the task manager you can find which process has the PID you got in the previous step. (You might need to add the PID column on the task manager)

C:\Users\vinko>netstat -ao -p tcp

```
Conexiones activas

  Proto  Dirección local          Dirección remota        Estado           PID
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:51373        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:51379        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:51381        ESTABLISHED     388
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:51382        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:51479        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:51481        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:51483        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:51485        ESTABLISHED     388
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:51487        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:51489        ESTABLISHED     388
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51381        127.0.0.1:1110         ESTABLISHED     5168
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51485        127.0.0.1:1110         ESTABLISHED     5168
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51489        127.0.0.1:1110         ESTABLISHED     5168
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59264        127.0.0.1:59265        ESTABLISHED     5168
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59265        127.0.0.1:59264        ESTABLISHED     5168
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59268        127.0.0.1:59269        ESTABLISHED     5168
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59269        127.0.0.1:59268        ESTABLISHED     5168
  TCP    192.168.1.34:51278     192.168.1.33:445       ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP    192.168.1.34:51383     67.199.15.132:80       ESTABLISHED     388
  TCP    192.168.1.34:51486     66.102.9.18:80         ESTABLISHED     388
  TCP    192.168.1.34:51490     74.125.4.20:80         ESTABLISHED     388
```

If you want to Disable Skype from listening on port 80 and 443, you can follow the link http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-skype-from-using-opening-and-listening-on-port-80-and-443-on-local-computer/

Comment: Yes, I hate how Skype tries to use port 80... I sometimes forget to change it, and then when I try to test some web thing I've written, Apache won't start.

Comment: It looks like the one new nod32 problem :(

Comment: Add Apache to its exceptions list to allow it to bind to port 80

Comment: You might want to change above netstat to: `netstat -aon | findstr :80` or even `netstat -aon | findstr /r ":80[^0-9]"` to get the line quicker. Also you can get pid from running `wmic process list brief` or `tasklist`.

Comment: Nothing running on port 80, here.

Comment: We can change access port of Skype at:
Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection
There will be checkbox with text "Use port 80..." just uncheck and test with restart Skype, access port will be changed

Comment: This was not the problem for me.

Answer (score 117):

**Run the httpd.exe from the command line** to get an accurate description of the problem.

I had the same error message and it turned out to be a miss configured ServerRoot path. Even after running setup_xampp.bat the httpd.conf had the wrong path.

My error.log was empty and starting the service does not give an informative error message.

Comment: This answer really helped me.  When I tried starting Apache by starting the service I just got a generic error message.  When I tried running C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\httpd.exe from the command window it told me exactly what line in my configuration file that it didn't like.

Comment: THIS!  Just `Run the httpd.exe from the command line`.  It will tell you EXACTLY what's wrong. I'm still confused why XAMPP's control panel doesn't provide error output.

Comment: Great Answer. In my case it turned out to be a Skype service listening on port 443 that was blocking apache, even though I run apache on port 80!

Comment: Fantastic Answer. After a lot of brick walls this provided the path towards the solution - THank you! Agree with @NathanJ.Brauer it's  unfortunate and short-sited that XAMPP doesn't relay/display this error information.

Comment: Check also your IP address. I changed to DHCP while Apache was set to listen on a fixed IP...

Comment: Seven years later, you just saved my bacon. I also agree with @NathanJ.Brauer in that CMD tells you exactly what the problem is, and XAMPP's control panel needs an update in that regard. For the record, I'm using Windows 10, XAMPP 3.2.2, and the error was: `Syntax error on line 39 of D:/XAMPP/apache/conf/httpd.conf: ServerRoot must be a valid directory`

Comment: I got this "httpd: Syntax error on line 186 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/disp_apache2.2.dll into server: The specified procedure could not be found."  I got something to look in to, thanks

Comment: This is probably the developer way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

the better way to resolve the issue is change the port number in Apache2\conf\httpd.conf . Change the port number as fallows::: Listen 8888 and ServerName machinename:8888 .Restart the Apache server after changing the port number.

Comment: It's not necessary to reinstall the server; it just needs to be restarted (actually, started, given that it isn't running in the first place). Also, this only resolves the issue in situations where you don't mind running Apache on another port.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I checked netstat, other processes running, firewall and changed httpd.conf, stopped antivirus, But all my efforts were in vain. :(

So finally the solution was to stop the IIS. And it worked :)

I guess IIS and apache cant work together. If anybody know any work around let us know.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431041/apache-xamp-and-iis-cant-work-together#431062

Answer (score 4):

Run the httpd.exe from the command line, as Tim mentioned. The path to PostgreSQL changed, nothing else was running on Port 80 and I didn't see anything in the `error.log` file.

I clone my boot drive/partition once the base is setup so I don't have to spend three days installing and retweaking everything. Turns I had reinstalled my WAPP stack and used very specific names/versions for PostgreSQL. **Windows will not return a specific error message unless you run the command from the command line.**

Comment: This is the approach that worked for me. Running via the CMD line I saw that there was an error in the vhosts.conf that only reared it's ugly head when the computer was restarted.

To run via the command line in windows type CMD in the Start Menu > Search Box and then the path to httpd.exe.

To discover the path to httpd.exe one way is to run "Services" from the Search Box, find Apache, right click on it and then copy the "path to the executable".

You can paste this into CMD with right click.

Answer (score 3):

Follow this step it will works fine.
 Go to **Control panel**-->**Programs and features**-->click Turn **Windows features on and off**--> see **IIS is Checked Or Not** If checked please unckeck **IIS** and restart the computer.After that Open services see **Web Deployement Agent** Service status if its started please stop.And also see **WampAppache and WampSqlID** if its not started please start manually. it will works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Hi i also meet this problem today.
And the log error in the Event viewer is as following
The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > 1.Wrapper php-cgi.exe cannot be accessed: (720005)Access is denied.
> > >
> > > 2.apache service monitor:the requested operation has failed

It is actual the access problem.So the solution as flowing is help me
change the php-cgi.exe security properties

- ***not inheit  from parent the permission...***
- ***please add the everyone user***

Answer (score 2):

if appache and IIS both are running at a time then there is a posibility to hang the apache service,,,,

when i stopped all IIS websites once and then restarted apache service and it works for me....Jai...

Answer (score 2):

Windows Vista Home Premium operating system issue: The easiest way to resolve the issue is to change the port number in Apache2\conf\httpd.conf.

Change the port number at the following lines. 'Listen' from 80 to 8888 and 'ServerName' machinename (ex:localhost) from 80 to 8888. Save then close. Open up Apache Service Monitor and restart service or go to Computer Management > Services and locate Apache 2.2 and start or restart.

Answer (score 1):

Remove apache from Control Panel and delete the apache folder from Program Files and restart the machine, then install apache again. This will solve the problem; if not do the following: Install IIS if not installed, then start IIS and stop it ... Using services start apache service... enjoy apache.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem twice. The first problem was fixed using the marked answer on this page (thank you for that). However, the second time proved a bit more difficult.

I found that in my httpd-vhosts.conf file that I made a mistake when assigning the document root to a domain name. Fixing this solved my problem. It is well worth checking (or even reverting to a blank copy) your httpd-vhosts.conf file for any errors and typo's.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using windows os and believe that skype is not the suspect, then you might want to check the task manager and check the "Show processes from all users" and make sure that there is NO entry for httpd.exe. Otherwise, end its process. That solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , i had to change the port :80 to :90 as port :80 was busy by some other system resource.

You can see the logs in the folder of Apache2.2\logs

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Always double check httpd.conf to see if document root is correctly pointing to an existing folder

```
#if you have c:\your-main-folder\www\
DocumentRoot "c:/your-main-folder/www/" 

#if you have c:\your-main-folder\www\sub-folder\
DocumentRoot "c:/your-main-folder/www/sub-folder/"
```

`DocumentRoot` points to a folder that must exist in your drive.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. when i restarted my wamp it turns to Yellow color icon but not green.
In services i stop all sql server services. after that it works for me..

- Two thinks that should must be take care. 
  1 ) port should be different
  2 ) stop those services which can be on port 80

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue, in my case i needed to add module in httpd.conf
the file was incomplete with incorrect keywords ( like LoadModule )
    go to command line, go to **C:\Apache24\bin**

C:\Apache24\bin **> httpd.exe**

the reason for the error can be known from the output of the above command

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys.  I found another culprit.  Recently SimplifyMedia added a photo sharing option.  Apparently it too uses port 80 and prevented Apache from starting up.  I hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

Me also coming the same problem.  The solution is goto add or remove programes then click the turn windows features on or off. Turn off the IIS.  That is turn off the 'Internet information services' and 'Internet information service removable web core'.  I chosed the remaining features are on.  Computer will ask to restart the system.  Restart ur computer and then install the apache http server. I got it.  Server succesfully working...

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was the result of having set the document root (in `httpd.conf`) to a directory that did not exist (I had just emptied htdocs of a previous project).

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 - administrator account

I needed to switch the account to an admin type account, in windows services

```
httpd.exe -k install
```

fails to add setup with enough user rights.