# Apache (xamp) and IIS cannot work together

Tags: apache, iis, apache2, xampp

I have XAMP 1.6.8 and IIS 5.0 installed on my PC(Windows XP SP3).

I'm unable to run them simultaneously. If IIS service is running, Apache throws the following error:

(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs Note the errors or messages above, and press the key to exit. 24...

Windows could not start the Apache2 on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 1.

---

#### Edit:

Apache runs on a different port 3128. And IIS (asp.net) usually runs on a different port.

Comment: Apache runs on a different port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80" means that, when it starts up, it tries to bind to port 80 on all available network interfaces. As IIS already has hogged one (or more) IPs to bind to, apache cannot get any and so will fail.

(I'm not sure if it will bind to any available IPs if you've configured it to bind to all, but one is already taken.)

So, configure Apache to bind to a different port (if you only have 1 IP address), or to bind to a different IP or range of IPs.

You do this by [changing the binding](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html). First find the Listen directive in the configuration file (httpd.conf) and change it. Currently it will say `"Listen 80"` (meaning all IPs), change it to say "`Listen 192.168.0.2:80`" to make it bind to that specified IP address.

You may have to edit the IIS configuration too to tell it to only bind to a single IP address too.

Answer (score 5):

You need to configure either Apache or IIS to listen on a different port.

You can also use [tcpview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to check which ports are in use by which applications since it sounds like you have a conflict.

Comment: You haven't set it up correctly then - the error it's giving is that it can't listen on port 80. It might be listening on 3128, but it's also trying to listen on 80.

Answer (score 1):

If you cant hit the arrow in centre of the circle, hit the arrow and then draw a circle around it. - I tried everything advised, uninstalled skype, no IIS running,added apache program to antivirus, still this did not solve the program

finally i changed apaches port from 80 to 82  look for Listen 80 in the httpd.conf and change this