# Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name

Tags: apache2, fedora

I have just installed Apache 2.2.17, and I am using it for the first time.

Now when I try to start the server using the command `service httpd start` it gives me the message:

> httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1 for ServerName

Now I think I have to set ServerName and the IP address as I search through Google. But I don't know in which file I have to set.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, you should set ServerName:

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CouldNotDetermineServerName

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername

You can find information on the layouts used by the various httpd distributions here:

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout

In your case the file to edit is /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: Hey thnks lot for your answares, I have edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and try to set ServerName as follows 
**Listen 80  
NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80  
    <VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
    ServerName www.example1.com  
    DocumentRoot /home/user/Softwares/mysite/
`</VirtualHost>*`*   

But still I am getting below error message..

**Starting httpd: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/user/Softwares/mysite] does not exist
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1 for ServerName**

Answer (score 105):

1. `sudo vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
2. Insert the following line at the httpd.conf: `ServerName localhost`
3. Just restart the Apache:  `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: On my RPi I had to put the httpd.conf file in /etc/apache2/conf.d for it to work.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 13.04, I had to put it into /etc/apache2/conf.d/httpd.conf as well, nothing else worked...

Comment: Thank you this resolved my issue as well.  I recently set the actual hostname in /etc/hosts and this broke apache until I set ServerName localhost in the global context.  Now the vhost is working again and the SSL cert is being served properly.

Comment: In my case I edited ```/etc/apache2/apache2.conf```

Answer (score 22):

I was NOT getting the ServerName wrong. Inside your VirtualHost configuration that is causing this warning message, it is the generic one near the top of your httpd.conf which is by default **commented** out.

Change

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
```

to:

```
  ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
```

Answer (score 14):

Under Debian Squeeze;

1. Edit Apache2 conf file : vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
2. Insert the following line at the apache2.conf: ServerName localhost
3. Restart Apache2: apache2ctl restart or /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Should work fine (it did solve the problem in my case)

tks noodl for the link on the different layouts. :)

Answer (score 5):

1. `sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
2. search for a text `ServerName` in nano editor `<Ctrl + W>`
3. Insert the following line at the httpd.conf: `ServerName localhost`
4. Just restart the Apache:  `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart`

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to ensure that the full qualified host name (FQDN) is listed in /etc/hosts.
This worked for me on Ubuntu v11.10 without having to change the default Apache configuration.

Answer (score 3):

**" To solve this problem You need set ServerName.**

1: `$ vim /etc/apache2/conf.d/name`
For example set add ServerName localhost or any other name:

2: ServerName localhost
Restart Apache 2

3: `$ service apache restart`
For this example I use **Ubuntu 11.10.1.125"**

Answer (score 1):

FQDN means the resolved name over DNS. It should be like "server-name.search-domain".

The warning you get just provides a notice that httpd can not find a FQDN, so it might not work right to handle a name-based virtual host. So make sure the expected FQDN is registered in your DNS server, or manually add the entry in `/etc/hosts` which is prior to hitting DNS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows there is something different sort of situation

First open `c:/apache24/conf/httpd.conf`.
The Apache folder is enough not specifically above path

After that you have to configure httpd.conf file.

Just after few lines there is pattern like:

```
#Listen _____________:80
Listen 80
```

Here You have to change for the `localhost`.

You have to enter ipv4 address for that you can open localhost.

Refer this video link and after that just bit more.

Change your environment variables:

[image: Image for Environment USER Variables in System setting]

In which you have to enter path:

```
c:apache24/bin
```

and
same in the SYSTEM variables

[image: Image is for system variables path]

If any query feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Two things seemed to do it for me:

1. Put all aliases for 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts in a single line (e.g. `127.0.0.1 localhost mysite.local myothersite.local`
2. Set `ServerName` in my httpd.conf to `0.0.0.0` (localhost or 127.0.0.1 didn't work for me)

Editing /etc/hosts got rid of long response times and setting the ServerName got rid of OP's warning for me.

Answer (score 0):

who are still couldnt resolve the problem and using mac then follow this

1.goto the root folder /

2. cd usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4

3.sudo nano httpd.conf

4.change #servername to ServerName 127.0.0.1:8080 press ctrl+o,+return+ctrl x

5.then restart the server apachectl restart

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, remove comment on these lines and set them as:

```
Line 227 : ServerName 127.0.0.1:80 
Line 235 : AllowOverride all 
Line 236 : Require all granted
```

Worked for me!

Comment: I had another service running on port 80 (organizr) so I had to modify the listener port (line 60). Also added firewall rule but not required.
```
Listen 4444
```

I had to do some digging to find an answer. Ultimately this answer did it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195641/windows-could-not-start-the-apache2-on-local-computer-problem?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: In what file and folder those line existed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents. Maybe it's useful for future readers.

I ran into this problem when using Apache within a Docker container. When I started a container from an image of the Apache webserver, this message appeared when I started it with `docker run -it -p 80:80 my-apache-container`.

However, after starting the container in detached mode, using `docker run -d -p 80:80 my-apache-container`, I was able to connect through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ubuntu 22.04

I installed the apache2 at the location **'/usr/local/apache2'**

I just edited the **'/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'** file.

run the following commands

**cd /usr/local/apache2/conf**

**sudo nano httpd.conf**

find this comment

**#ServerName [www.example.com:80](http://www.example.com:80)**, in my case it is at line 197

after that add this

**ServerName localhost**

**don't modify anything else in this file!**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it.

```
hostnamectl set-hostname youfirstdomain.com
```

vi **/etc/hosts**

add this line

```
0.0.0.0 youfirstdomain.com
```

Instead of **0.0.0.0** put your **IP address of the server**

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the following error, it could be due to permissions, had restarted apache as root and it worked!

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```