# Installing localhost and having errors

Tags: php, apache, cmd

Alright, when I go to install Apache 24 by command prompt with this code going into it's bin.

```
httpd.exe -k install
```

then I run `httpd.exe`

I get this error.

```
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified do
main name, using fe80::d939:4e4:4915:276. Set the 'ServerName' directive globall
y to suppress this message
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its acces
s permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its acces
s permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

and then I **pinged my port** that is using **80**. I get the PID of 4 which is my system with a description of NT Kernel & System.

Anyway I can fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1 for ServerName](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856205/starting-httpd-httpd-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to run command prompt as administrator

Comment: I have already attempted. I done some googleing and it seems like it can't have another service running on that port.

Comment: you could go for port 8080. just edit the httpd.conf file to the line that says 'Listen 80' and change it to 'Listen 8080'

Comment: One thing tho. When I try to connect to localhost:8080 I get forbidden access. But it did successfully install. Also it still won't allow my to start the service.

Answer (score 0):

The port 80 is already used and when you try to modify it in the file conf/httpd.conf nothing changes. My mistake was that I assumed that the install folder is the one I have chosen to use via installation. If you go to services and find the Apache service and check the path to executable, you will see that it is not pointing to the folder that you thought you have installed it on. However, if you change the line "Listen 80" to "Listen 8080' in the httpd.conf file from the folder taken from the service path, it will most likely allow you to start the service.