# apache fail to restart

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, restart

I am trying to figure out a php-mysql connection problem on ubuntu when I encounter a problem with restarting apache. I got the following error when running:

```
apache2ctl configtest

apache2: Syntax error on line 236 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/index.html: Expected <\/p>This> but saw <\/p> 
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

The line 236 shows:

```
Include conf.d/

The line 3 of index.html is:
<\/p>
```

**NOTE: editor please help with the above html tags.**
When testing on the browser: 127.0.0.1, the index page shows just fine. I've searched a lot but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: What is HTML code doing inside apache2.conf? This error relates to "apache2: Syntax error on line 236 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf"

Comment: Can you paste that index.html's content?

Answer (score 1):

The `index.html` file doesn't belong in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`. Please move it to an appropriate place (perhaps your DocumentRoot).

Comment: Removing the index page works, thanks! Now the test shows:
'apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
Syntax OK'
Do I need to change something somewhere?

Comment: That is more common: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856205/starting-httpd-httpd-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified

Comment: This link works! What works for me is the second suggestion about changing /etc/apache2/httpd.conf. This also helps me solve my php-mysql connection problem that I intended to ask after this! Thank you all!  This place is paradise :)