# Install and Start httpd in AWS Launch Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to make a Launch Configuration for my AWS Cloud Environment.

I wan't to install httpd and start it up on the fly, when the autoscaling group spins up a new EC2 instance.

I can SSH into the instance manually and install httpd with:
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install httpd -y
sudo service httpd start

But I can't make it happen, with the Launch Configuration under Advance Details -> User Data
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install httpd -y
sudo service httpd start

Any ideas why it's not the same?

[image]

*Update*
After adding `#!/bin/bash` as @Mark-B suggested, then service is kindda installed. It gives the following error when restarting the service. Maybe it could be a hint for you, to figure out what is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User-data can be used for more than running startup scripts. To indicate to the cloud-init process that the user-data is a script, you need to add this as the first line of your user-data:

`#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Hi Mark. That makes sense! Thanks. Any ideas, why the server still isn't starting up the same way, as when I start it up manually?    sudo service httpd status
   ---  >    httpd (pid  2734) is running...   so it apparently looks fine...

Comment: @RedHawkDK that second issue looks like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856205/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name