# phpmyadmin not working in mac installed dependencies but still no good

Tags: macos, apache

Hi guys I am having trouble in mac installing phpmyadmin, local host seems to work but every time I run `sudo apachectl start/restart/stop` I am getting this 
`httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for my-pc
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

localhost is working, I installed mysql, phpmyadmin, and php using cask

Comment: Despite being in the Ubuntu site, this seems to address this rather well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n

Comment: This one also seems to be pretty good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856205/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name

Comment: I solved mine by reinstalling phpmyadmin and uncommenting some lines in httpd.conf file

Comment: Depending how you installed Apache, you might have to hunt around for the configuration file (since Homebrew, the official Apache install process, and the MacOS web server probably all use different paths). This answer may help you find the correct file: https://serverfault.com/questions/155113/how-can-i-tell-which-config-file-apache-is-using

Comment: Yeah man, thus I reinstalled phpmyadmin and httpd and reconfigure some lines and its good now thanks anyway for the effort man :)