# Error installing and starting Apache Web Server using Gzip Compression

Tags: apache, web, webserver

I tried to install the Apache 2.4 web server on my local machine and I got the error below.

**
Errors reported here must be corrected before the service can be started.
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::7908:85c9:d022:6dbc. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message**

I ran the command `httpd.exe -k install` to install the Apache and `httpd.exe -k start` to start the server and see if I could bypass error.

Comment: AFAIK that's a warning, not an error. I'm assuming your server is running. Did you try following the instruction from that warning: _"Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message"_? that might actually do what it says and get rid of the message.

Comment: Yes, it's actually a warning.Thank you, that was helpful. I fixed it already

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a Server Name in the httpd.conf :

1. List item `C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf` or `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` with notepad or any other text editor.
2. Search for this line in config file `#ServerName www.example.com:80`
3. Uncomment this line by removing # from the first of line and edit to `ServerName 127.0.0.1`
4. Save the file, exit and try restarting the server

Source : [Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856205/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name)

Answer (score 0):

So, I came across a doc online that fixed the error.

All that was needed to find the line with `#ServerName www.example.com:80` in `C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf`, uncomment it, and maybe replace the URL with `127.0.0.1` or as it suits.

Link to the document:
https://monovm.com/blog/apache-could-not-determine-the-server-qualified-domain-name/