# Cannot start Apache service in Windows system service administration

Tags: windows, apache, service, startup

Once I restarted my PC, then Apache 2.25 rejected to work anymore. I went to the system service administration, found couldn't get Apache service started.

The possibility that the port Apache commonly using occupied by other processes is excluded. Actually the port was used by Adobe Flash Media Server, but I terminated all the related services and made sure the port was available but I still couldn't startup it. Then I went through `httpd.conf` again, all the configs remain the same as it works normally before, and nothing wrong was feedback from the Apache logs.

Can anyone can give some clues to repair it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your apache is not starting with httpd.exe, Then there could be many possibilities. Try to start the httpd using console (command prompt)

```
cd "\Program Files\path_to_apache_installation\Apache2.2\bin"
httpd.exe
```

If the apache console stops right away, Check the apache logs for some clues

```
cd ..\logs
more < error.log
```

The logs will convey you more details why apache is not starting

Comment: Hi Leo, nothing was recorded into logs. The only message was when I start Apache service Windows' popup

Comment: What does the pop up says ?

Comment: it's like "Windows could not start the Apache2 on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log...and so on"

Comment: What does system event log says ?

Comment: "DocumentRoot must be a directory."  Actually I'm using VirtualHost, whose DocumentRoot path is correct.

Comment: The documentroot should be always be valid, and distinct from virtualhost document root. I just casually modified the original the folder name which the documentroot refers to. I find another post [Windows could not start the Apache2 on Local Computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195641/windows-could-not-start-the-apache2-on-local-computer-problem) should be helpful to ones who have similar problems. Anyway Leo, thank you for reminding me to check the windows event log, which I never thought of before.

Comment: LOL :D .. My pleasure #Sarotti

Comment: Start Apache from the command line, from apache bin using the httpd command. It will give you specific details about the problem.